# getbootstrap modal close, sending parameter with querystring

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the getbootstrap.com to create a modal window. 
Within this modal'll have a form where the click on the radio button should close the window sending the parameter to the window that opened.

With close the modal?

```
function ModalClose() {
    $('#myModal2Busca').modal('hide')
}
```

and modal put

```
<input name="chk" type="radio" value='<%#Eval("intid")%>' onclick="parent.ModalFecha()" />
```

It did not work, tried with window.close () does not, tried to put the javascript function in the modal and nothing. 
**how to close this modal? and preferably, sending the querystring value to the page that called**

Note: The modal calls another page `iframe`

font: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I 
parent.location = "url.aspx? id = '+ + This.Value'"

he refreshes the page down, so closes the modal